# color cells in a range depending on the value of the previous cell in the same column with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, conditional-statements

I need to color cells in several columns depending on the value of the previous cell in the same column with google app script. When the value of a given cell, let's say C3, is bigger than the previous one,  C2, color must be green, otherwise it must be red. Is there a way to do it only with conditional formatting or is better to use google app script?
Thanks for answering

Comment: You can do the coloring of one or more cells via google sheets [API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting)

Comment: can you explain better?